# What's the most appropriate way to derive and validate a model with hierarchical data

Tags: cross-validation, multilevel-analysis, validation

I am working on a model to predict the risk of some outcomes and could really use some advise:

Let's say we have x  number of patients, each patient have anywhere between 0 and y number of visits (such as ED visits or hospitalization); we want to develop a model to predict the risk of certain outcome (say hospitalization within the next 30 days) each time the patient comes for a visit (say each time a patient shows up at the ED).

In this dataset, we will have visit level variables (such as main reason for the visit, timing of visit, etc.) and patient level variables (such as demographic variables).

My two questions:
1. Would a hierarchical model (visit level and patient level, with random intercept) be a valid approach? In this approach, each patient will have its own intercept, essentially capturing the unknown and unobserved "latent" characters of the patient on that risk we are trying to predict. One concern is the ability (or lack of ability) of the model derived this way to accurately predict the risk for new patients not in the derivation dataset, as there is no prior information for the intercept for the new patients and the accuracy would be significantly worse than what you would get predicting existing patients; 
2. The related question of the most appropriate way to derive and validate such a model. One potential approach would be to simply randomly split the dataset into two on the visit level, and use one to derive and the other to validate. The issues include overfitting as most patients will be included in both datasets. Another approach would be to split the patients into two groups, one to derive the model and the other to validate, so that the validation set will have entirely different patients compared to the derivation set. Is either of these two approach valid, if we are talking about a hierarchical model? Or is there a third, and better or more appropriate way to handle this?

I realize that what I have said may be confusing or I may not have provided all relevant information; in that case, please let me know how I can clarify or which additional information would be helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Modeler